# Vertical spacing in tables with math

Tags: tables, math-mode, spacing, booktabs

How can I force LaTeX to vertically center math in a table taking into account subscripts, superscripts, etc? It appears from the output below that LaTeX vertically centered the `$JV$` and added the tildes, hats, and subscripts as an afterthought. The result is extra space under the `$JV$` and little space above the hats and tildes.

[image: mytable]

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,svgnames]{beamer} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
%==============================================================================%
  \begin{frame}{}
    \begin{table}
      \begin{center}
        \rowcolors{1}{}{RoyalBlue!20}             % alternate row coloring
        \newlength{\oldtabcolsep}                 % keep track of old \tabcolsep
        \setlength{\oldtabcolsep}{\tabcolsep}     % 6.0pt
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}               % so coloring doesn't run off
                                                  % ends of the table
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}         % because math expressions
                                                  % almost run into each other
        \begin{tabular}{l<{\hspace{\oldtabcolsep}}l<{\hspace{\oldtabcolsep}}l}  
          \toprule
          Estimator & ME & MAE \\
          \specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt} % so row-coloring aligns
          \(\widehat{JV}_{\text{na\"{\i}ve}}\)          & 4.37e-07 & 4.37e-07 \\
          \(\widetilde{JV}_{\text{na\"{\i}ve}}\)        & 3.88e-07 & 3.88e-07 \\
          \(\widehat{JV}\)                              & 1.33e-06 & 1.33e-06 \\
          \(\widetilde{JV}\)                            & 1.20e-06 & 1.20e-06 \\
          \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
      \end{center}
    \end{table}
  \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: 1: Don't use center-environment inside a floating environment; see [Should I use center or centering for figures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures). 2. The "new" package `tabu` provides more flexibility to create such tables. 3. If you don't use the package `tabu` you can use the package `cellspace`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert a strut in each row, instead of acting on `\arraystretch`:

```
\rowcolors{1}{}{RoyalBlue!20}             % alternate row coloring
\newlength{\oldtabcolsep}                 % keep track of old \tabcolsep
\setlength{\oldtabcolsep}{\tabcolsep}     % 6.0pt
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}               % so coloring doesn't run off
                                          % ends of the table
\newcommand{\mystrut}{\vrule height 20pt depth 10pt width 0pt }

 \begin{tabular}
   {>{\mystrut}l<{\hspace{\oldtabcolsep}}
    l<{\hspace{\oldtabcolsep}}
    l
   }
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Estimator\hspace*{\oldtabcolsep}} & ME & MAE \\
\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt} % so row-coloring aligns
\(\widehat{JV}_{\text{na\"{\i}ve}}\)          & 4.37e-07 & 4.37e-07 \\
\(\widetilde{JV}_{\text{na\"{\i}ve}}\)        & 3.88e-07 & 3.88e-07 \\
\(\widehat{JV}\)                              & 1.33e-06 & 1.33e-06 \\
\(\widetilde{JV}\)                            & 1.20e-06 & 1.20e-06 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Since the strut is automatically inserted in the first column, you have to correct it in the header line. Here the dimensions set for the strut are exaggerated; a perhaps satisfying setting may be

```
\newcommand{\mystrut}{\vrule height 3ex depth 1.5ex width 0pt }
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to using the strut approach over `\arraystretch`? Also, I ran this code and found that there's still more space below the $\widehat{JV}$ than below it. I'd like for the mathematics to be vertically centered...**including** the extra subscripts, superscripts, hats, etc.

Comment: @brianjd I wouldn't include hats and subscripts: the numbers in columns 2 and 3 visually dominate the row. Just add some vertical space so that hats and subscripts don't go too near the the edge: they span different vertical space, but the eye is not led by them.

Comment: Agreed. Once extra space is added it's not so much of an issue anymore. I think I made this more difficult than it needed to be just out of curiosity for how LaTeX works.

Answer (score 2):

Until now you haven't gave any feedback. Now I will switch my comment to an answer.

First of all don't use the environment `center` inside the floating environment. An explanation is given in the answer: [Should I use center or centering for figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures)

<sub>I know inside beamer `figure` and co. are not floating-environment in the LaTeX meaning.</sub>

---

**The package [cellspace](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cellspace):**

The package cellspace have a simple syntax. It provides only 2 length and a special column prefix `S`.

The two length are `\cellspacebottomlimit` and `\cellspacetoplimit` which can be changed by `\setlength`. In your example I set both length to 5pt.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,svgnames]{beamer} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\begin{document}
%==============================================================================%
  \begin{frame}{}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \cellspacebottomlimit=5pt
    \cellspacetoplimit=5pt
%      \begin{center}
        \rowcolors{1}{}{RoyalBlue!20}             % alternate row coloring
        \newlength{\oldtabcolsep}                 % keep track of old \tabcolsep
        \setlength{\oldtabcolsep}{\tabcolsep}     % 6.0pt
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}               % so coloring doesn't run off
                                                  % ends of the table
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}         % because math expressions
                                                  % almost run into each other
        \begin{tabular}{Sl<{\hspace{\oldtabcolsep}}l<{\hspace{\oldtabcolsep}}l}  
          \toprule
          Estimator & ME & MAE \\
          \specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt} % so row-coloring aligns
          \(\widehat{JV}_{\text{na\"{\i}ve}}\)          & 4.37e-07 & 4.37e-07 \\
          \(\widetilde{JV}_{\text{na\"{\i}ve}}\)        & 3.88e-07 & 3.88e-07 \\
          \(\widehat{JV}\)                              & 1.33e-06 & 1.33e-06 \\
          \(\widetilde{JV}\)                            & 1.20e-06 & 1.20e-06 \\
          \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
%      \end{center}
    \end{table}
  \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

The result is seen in picture below:
[image]

*Note:* The package `cellspace` is incompatible with `siunitx`. If you want to use both packages you have to create your own file `Mycellspace.sty` and copy the contents of `cellspace` in the new file. Now you have to change

```
\newcolumntype{S}[1]{>{\bcolumn #1\@nil}#1<{\ecolumn}}
```

to

```
\newcolumntype{O}[1]{>{\bcolumn #1\@nil}#1<{\ecolumn}}
```

You need a unknown column type.

---

**The package [tabu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrEMm.png):**

The package tabu offers more flexibility as shown below. The package provides the lengths `\tabulinesep` and `\extrarowsep` to control the space. In the example I set `\tabulinesep=1.5mm`

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,svgnames]{beamer} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
%==============================================================================%
  \begin{frame}{}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \tabulinesep=1.5mm
        \rowcolors{1}{}{RoyalBlue!20}             % alternate row coloring
        \newlength{\oldtabcolsep}                 % keep track of old \tabcolsep
        \setlength{\oldtabcolsep}{\tabcolsep}     % 6.0pt
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}               % so coloring doesn't run off
                                                  % ends of the table
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}         % because math expressions
                                                  % almost run into each other
        \begin{tabu}{l<{\hspace{\oldtabcolsep}}l<{\hspace{\oldtabcolsep}}l}  
          \toprule
          Estimator & ME & MAE \\
          \specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt} % so row-coloring aligns
          \(\widehat{JV}_{\text{na\"{\i}ve}}\)          & 4.37e-07 & 4.37e-07 \\
          \(\widetilde{JV}_{\text{na\"{\i}ve}}\)        & 3.88e-07 & 3.88e-07 \\
          \(\widehat{JV}\)                              & 1.33e-06 & 1.33e-06 \\
          \(\widetilde{JV}\)                            & 1.20e-06 & 1.20e-06 \\
          \bottomrule
        \end{tabu}
    \end{table}
  \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

The result is similar to `cellspace` but it works with `siunitx`:

[image]

Comment: You've turned me on to the tabu package. It looks great. In this case, though, is there really any advantage to using `tabulinesep` over `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}`? It's still the case that there's less space above the hat in the $JV$ than there is below. I want the vertical spacing to be the same. `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}` doesn't seem to do it any better/worse (sorry I didn't respond earlier)