# How to make a perfect colour filled threeparttable table?

Tags: tables, spacing, color

A three line table is used for my report. I want to fill `lightgray` background color to the whole table, but there is white space between rows, how to eliminate this issue?

1. Without `\addlinespace`: there is still white space around rules
   [image]
2. With `\addlinespace`: this is ideal spacing between rows, but how to fill colour as well for these white spaces?
   [image]

---

```
  \usepackage{colortbl}
  \definecolor{Lightgray}{RGB}{235,235,235}
```

Code:

```
  \begin{table} [htpb]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.9 \textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}[b]

  \caption{Size and shape distribution for a sampled rock riprap} 
  \label{tab:size_shape}
  \begin{tabular} { p{0.15 \textwidth}  p{0.10 \textwidth} p{0.10 \textwidth} p{0.10 \textwidth} p{0.15 \textwidth}  } 
  \toprule
  \rowcolor{Lightgray}& Small    &  Medium &  Large & Shape fraction \\        \cmidrule{1-5}  \addlinespace
  \rowcolor{Lightgray}Compact    & 10\% &  44\% & 7\% & 61\% \\ \addlinespace
  \rowcolor{Lightgray}Flat       & 4\%  &  10\% & 4\% & 18\% \\ \addlinespace       
  \rowcolor{Lightgray}Elongated  & 5\%  &  12\% & 4\% & 21\% \\ \addlinespace
  \midrule
  \rowcolor{Lightgray}Size fraction  & 19\% & 66\% & 15\% & 100\% \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{threeparttable}
  \end{minipage}
  \end{table}
```

**Edit 1:**  Using `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}` gets proper spacing between rows without `\addlinespace`. The remaining issue is: how to get ride of the whihte space for rules?

**Edit 2:** The solution of [Professional-looking tables with alternating row colors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33758) still could not eliminate white space after `midline` or `cmidrule`. Hence `white` colour is used for the row after `midline` to `hide` the white space. If wrong please correct me.

See the table created by the new commands of that solution:
[image]

```
   \begin{table} [htpb]
   \centering
   \begin{minipage}[b]{0.9 \textwidth}
   \centering
   \begin{threeparttable}[b]

   \caption{Size and shape distribution for a sampled rock riprap} 
   \label{tab:size_shape}
   \begin{tabular} { p{0.15 \textwidth}  p{0.10 \textwidth} p{0.10 \textwidth} p{0.10 \textwidth} p{0.15 \textwidth}  } 
   \topline
   \headcol & Small  &  Medium &  Large & Shape fraction \\% \cmidrule{1-5}  
   \midline
   \rowcol Compact    & 10\% &  44\% & 7\% & 61\% \\ 
   \rowcol Flat       & 4\%  &  10\% & 4\% & 18\% \\ % \cellcolor{lightgray}  
   \rowcol Elongated  & 5\%  &  12\% & 4\% & 21\% \\ 
   \midline
   \rowcol Size fraction  & 19\% & 66\% & 15\% & 100\% \\
   \bottomlinec  %\bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
   \end{threeparttable}
   \end{minipage}
   \end{table}
```

Besides, if you enlarge the table and look carefully, you will see few thin white lines in the heading row! Is that normal?

See below:
[image: lines]

Comment: See Werner's answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33758.

Comment: The answer codes of `tex.stackexchange.com/q/33758` seems not working.

Comment: Can you please add to your question a complete document with the code you used to produce the image? (I mean the one containing the commands from the answer I linked to in my previous comment).

Comment: Please look to the final commands to produce the table below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After looking into the new commands provided by [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33758/professional-looking-tables-with-alternating-row-colors), it seems that the `mideline` is redefined by 3 rules with top colour, middle colour and bottom colour.

So two new commands were added to make a perfect colour filled table:

1. Middle line connecting heading row and the second row

   ```
   \colorlet{blcolor}{gray!80}

   \newcommand{\rowmidlineHR}{\arrayrulecolor{tableheadcolor}
     \specialrule{\aboverulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
     \arrayrulecolor{black}\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}%
     \arrayrulecolor{tablerowcolor}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
     \arrayrulecolor{black}}
     % Command \rowmidlinewc consists of 3 rules
     % (top colour tableheadcolor, middle colour black, bottom colour tablerowcolor)
   ```
2. Secondary gray middle line

   ```
   \newcommand{\rowmidlineG}{\arrayrulecolor{tablerowcolor}%
     \specialrule{\aboverulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
     \arrayrulecolor{blcolor}\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}%
     \arrayrulecolor{tablerowcolor}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
     \arrayrulecolor{black}}
   % Command \rowmidlineG consists of 3 rules
   % (top colour tablerowcolor, middle colour black, bottom colour tablerowcolor)
   ```

Final table:
[image: perfect table]

and the codes:

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\begin{table} [htpb]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.9 \textwidth}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}[b]

\caption{Size and shape distribution for a sampled rock riprap} 
\label{tab:size_shape}
\begin{tabular} { p{0.15 \textwidth}  p{0.10 \textwidth} p{0.10 \textwidth} p{0.10 \textwidth} p{0.15 \textwidth}  } 
\topline
\headcol & Small  &  Medium &  Large & Shape fraction \\
\rowmidlineHR  % Head Rule
\rowcol Compact    & 10\% &  44\% & 7\% & 61\% \\ 
\rowcol Flat       & 4\%  &  10\% & 4\% & 18\% \\ 
\rowcol Elongated  & 5\%  &  12\% & 4\% & 21\% \\ 
\rowmidlineG % Gray midline
\rowcol Size fraction  & 19\% & 66\% & 15\% & 100\% \\
\bottomlinec
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have a command to color the whole tabular. You have directly the expected result.

However, in order to use `{NiceTabular}` in `{threeparttable}`, you have first to tell `threeparttable` that it should take into account the environment `{NiceTabular}` (with the dedicated hook of `threeparttable`):

```
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{env/threeparttable/begin}
{\TPT@hookin{NiceTabular}\TPT@hookin{NiceTabular*}}
\makeatother
```

For the whole MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{env/threeparttable/begin}
{\TPT@hookin{NiceTabular}\TPT@hookin{NiceTabular*}}
\makeatother


\begin{table} [htpb]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.9 \textwidth}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}[b]

\caption{Size and shape distribution for a sampled rock riprap} 
\label{tab:size_shape}
\begin{NiceTabular} { p{0.15 \textwidth}  p{0.10 \textwidth} p{0.10 \textwidth} p{0.10 \textwidth} p{0.15 \textwidth}  } 
\CodeBefore
  \arraycolor[gray]{0.9}
\Body
\toprule
& Small    &  Medium &  Large & Shape fraction \\ \cmidrule{1-5}  \addlinespace
Compact    & 10\% &  44\% & 7\% & 61\% \\ \addlinespace
Flat       & 4\%  &  10\% & 4\% & 18\% \\ \addlinespace       
Elongated  & 5\%  &  12\% & 4\% & 21\% \\ \addlinespace
\midrule
Size fraction  & 19\% & 66\% & 15\% & 100\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{minipage}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]