# How to generate a table of trigonometric functions that can be broken across pages?

Tags: tables, programming

Consider the following screenshot.

[image]

The features I want to have are:

- I can shrink the page size and the table is allowed to break across pages.
- The background of odd rows must be different from that of the even rows to ease reading.
- The values must be calculated automatically rather than by hand-made data entry.

### MWE

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\topskip=0pt
\begin{longtable}{*2{|>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}}|}\hline
\theta & \sin \theta\\
\foreach \x in {0,10,...,360}{\x & \FPeval\temp{round(\x:3)}\temp\\}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution should combine (1) [`longtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable), (2) [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) with the `table` option, (3) either [`fp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp) or [`pgfmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33771/1410 for zebra stripes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

More easily, you can use the [calculator](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/calculator/) package which will allow you to evaluate the trigonometric functions. Also the [supertabular](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/supertabular) package will allow you to make the repeated heading/footer on each table.

Here is a simpler example:

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{theangle}

\tablefirsthead{
    \cline{2-4}
    \rowcolor{white}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ } &
    \cos \theta & \sin \theta & \tan \theta &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{ } \\
    \hline
      }
\tablehead{
    \rowcolor{white}
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{Table continued \ldots}\\
    \cline{2-4}
    \rowcolor{white}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ } &
    \cos \theta & \sin \theta & \tan \theta &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{ } \\
    \hline
      }
\tablelasttail{
    \rowcolor{white}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ } &
    \cos \theta & \sin \theta & \tan \theta &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{ }\\
    \cline{2-4}
      }
\tabletail{
    \hline
    \rowcolor{white}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ } &
    \cos \theta & \sin \theta & \tan \theta &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{  } \\
    \cline{2-4}
    \rowcolor{white}
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{Continued on next page \ldots}\\
      }

\rowcolors{2}{gray!50}{white}
\begin{center}
\begin{supertabular}{*5{|>{$}c<{$}}|}
\forloop{theangle}{0}{\value{theangle} < 360}{
    \arabic{theangle}^\circ &
    \DEGREESCOS{\value{theangle}}{\solx} \solx &
    \DEGREESSIN{\value{theangle}}{\solx} \solx &
    \DEGREESTAN{\value{theangle}}{\solx} \solx &
    \arabic{theangle}^\circ\\
    \addtocounter{theangle}{4} 
      }
\end{supertabular}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

**Output**
[image: Table Start]
[image: Table Bottom]
[image: Table Continued]

Comment: May be with example to benefit wider audience.

Answer (score 18):

### Packages

- `xcolor` with the option `table` for `\rowcolor`
- `pgfplotstable` (and internally `pgfmath`) that is used to build the entire table. The `pgfmath` package helps us to create the trigonometric values (which are all built-in)
- `longtable` to allow page-breaks in one table (needs multiple passes)
- `siunitx` to typeset numbers in tables (`pgfmath` does a good job on number printing already, but that is not very well suited for tables)
- `booktabs` for nice rules.

### `\pgfplotstableset`

#### Auxiliary styles

Styles prepended with an `@` are new styles created by me. Neither is the `@` needed (just to separate `pgfplotstable`’s styles from mine) nor are the names set in stone. These styles are used with the `.list` handler to ease the creation of the columns.

The line

```
@create function/.list={sin,cos,tan,cot,cosec,sec},
```

builds the main columns, note that the `csc` function is named `cosec` in PGF. The column is named `cosec` but I later change the `column name` to `csc`. (One may also note that one should use proper column names, e.g. `$\phi$` and `$\sin \phi$` instead of empty column names and non-math-mode but math-function names.)

Note the `string type` key, this deactivates PGF printing number features (but not the PGF math calculation of the columns).

#### `longtable` setup

The basic keys `begin table` and `end table` are used to set the internal table environment from `tabular` to `longtable`.

The `every head row` style is (mis-)used to set up the special rows (these are `longtable` features). See the `longtable` manual for more.

#### `\pgfplotstablenew`

Let's create 91 rows (+ header (e.g. `longtable` preamble)):

```
\pgfplotstablenew[
    columns={left,sin,cos,tan,cot,sec,cosec,right},
    ]{91}\myTable
```

#### `\sisetup`

Certain `siunitx` settings are made before the actual typesetting (this could have been done in the `S[…]` column specifications, too). These settings are needed so that `siunitx` doesn’t try to setup numbers in scientific notation as PGF math may give an output in the form of `1.746e-2` (pretty much everywhere).

#### `\pgfplotstabletypeset`

Finally!

Here the auxiliary styles for setting up the `column type`s are used.

The `@secure header` uses the `\multicolumn` macro to hide the content from `siunitx`’s parsing. The usual approach by putting the content in braces, e.g. `{sin}` doesn’t appear to be working here.

The `left` and the `right` column only uses `r` columns (we could use `S` here, too) with an appended `\si{\degree}` via `array`’s `<{…}` syntax. This is also the reason the header needs an empty `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` entry.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\pgfplotstableset{
    % helpers
    @create function/.style={
        create on use/#1/.style={
            create col/expr=#1(\thisrow{left})}},
    @secure header/.style={
        columns/#1/.append style={
            column name=\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}},
    @set columns to siunitx type 1/.style={
        columns/#1/.append style={
            string type,
            column type={S[table-format=1.4]}}},
    @set columns to siunitx type 2/.style={
        columns/#1/.append style={
            string type,
            string replace={inf}{\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\infty$}},
            column type={S[table-format=2.4]}}},
    @set columns to siunitx type 3/.style={
        columns/#1/.append style={
            string type,
            string replace={inf}{\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\infty$}},
            column type={S[table-format=2.3]}}},
    @set columns to basic style/.style={
        columns/#1/.append style={
            column type={r<{\si{\degree}}}}},
    @set empty header/.style={
        columns/#1/.append style={
            column name={\multicolumn{1}{c}{}}}},
    %
    % the left and right columns
    create on use/left/.style={
        create col/expr=\pgfplotstablerow},
    create on use/right/.style={
        create col/expr={90-\thisrow{left}}},
    %
    % Let's start: the functions
    @create function/.list={sin,cos,tan,cot,cosec,sec},
    % The longtable setup
    begin table=\begin{longtable},
    end table=\end{longtable},
    every head row/.append style={
        before row=\toprule,
        after row=%
        \midrule \endhead
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & {cos} & {sin} & {cot} & {tan} & {csc} & {sec} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\dots}\\ \bottomrule
        \endfoot
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & {cos} & {sin} & {cot} & {tan} & {csc} & {sec} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} \\ \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot},
    every odd row/.style={before row={\rowcolor[gray]{.9}}},
}
\pgfplotstablenew[
    columns={left,sin,cos,tan,cot,sec,cosec,right},
    ]{91}\myTable
\begin{document}
\sisetup{scientific-notation = fixed, fixed-exponent = 0, table-auto-round=true}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    % the column types
    @set columns to siunitx type 1/.list={sin,cos},
    @set columns to siunitx type 2=tan,
    @set columns to siunitx type 3/.list={cot,sec,cosec},
    @set columns to basic style/.list={left,right},
    % setup for the headers
    @secure header/.list={sin,cos,tan,cot,sec},
    @set empty header/.list={left,right},
    columns/cosec/.append style={column name={\multicolumn{1}{c}{csc}}},
]\myTable
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to modify it to get the numbers with comma instead of dot? I mean 0,5678 insted of 0.5678?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin As the numbers are typeset by `siunitx` you can use all `siunitx`' settings and customization. If your document for example follows the German typesetting rules you can do `\sisetup{locale=DE}` which includes the setting `output-decimal-marker = {,}`.