# Algorithm for 'Plugging in' Values to Tables

Tags: tables, algorithms, excel

Simply, if I have a table of the form:

```
    \begin{tabular}{l r r r r r l r r r r r}
    \hline
    {}&{}&{}&$n$&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&$n$&{}&{}\\
    \cline{2-6}\cline{8-12}
    {}&1&2&3&4&5&{}&1&2&3&4&5\\
    \hline
$Q(n+0)$&1&1&2&3&3&$Q(n+100)$&48&54&54&50&60\\
$Q(n+5)$&4&5&5&6&6&$Q(n+105)$&52&54&58&60&53\\
$Q(n+10)$&6&8&8&8&10&$Q(n+110)$&60&60&52&62&66\\
$Q(n+15)$&9&10&11&11&12&$Q(n+115)$&55&62&68&62&58\\
$Q(n+20)$&12&12&12&16&14&$Q(n+120)$&72&58&61&78&57\\
$Q(n+25)$&14&16&16&16&16&$Q(n+125)$&71&68&64&63&73\\
$Q(n+30)$&20&17&17&20&21&$Q(n+130)$&63&71&72&72&80\\
$Q(n+35)$&19&20&22&21&22&$Q(n+135)$&61&71&77&65&80\\
$Q(n+40)$&23&23&24&24&24&$Q(n+140)$&71&69&77&75&73\\
$Q(n+45)$&24&24&32&24&25&$Q(n+145)$&77&79&76&80&79\\
$Q(n+50)$&30&28&26&30&30&$Q(n+150)$&75&82&77&80&80\\
$Q(n+55)$&28&32&30&32&32&$Q(n+155)$&78&83&83&78&85\\
$Q(n+60)$&32&32&40&33&31&$Q(n+160)$&82&85&84&84&88\\
$Q(n+65)$&38&35&33&39&40&$Q(n+165)$&83&87&88&87&86\\
$Q(n+70)$&37&38&40&39&40&$Q(n+170)$&90&88&87&92&90\\
$Q(n+75)$&39&42&40&41&43&$Q(n+175)$&91&92&92&94&92\\
$Q(n+80)$&44&43&43&46&44&$Q(n+180)$&93&94&94&96&94\\
$Q(n+85)$&45&47&47&46&48&$Q(n+185)$&96&96&96&96&96\\
$Q(n+90)$&48&48&48&48&48&$Q(n+190)$&96&128&72&96&115\\
$Q(n+95)$&64&41&52&54&56&$Q(n+195)$&100&84&114&110&93\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
}
```

is there a way that I can automatically edit the numerical values in the syntax?  I'd like to do this so I can just take a table of values in excel and basically 'copy' the values in those tables to this form so that I make all the necessary tables relatively quickly.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are various ways to convert Excel tables to LaTeX source depending on your OS: see [Comprehensive list of tools that simplify the generation of LaTeX tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49414). (Possible duplicate)

Comment: @Alan Do these methods rely on default templates or would it be possible to tell it to convert values in cells A1....An B1...Bn to the respective slots in a template as above?  For example, I know Gnumeric and a variety of others make a basic table for you just by transferring over but it's important in this case that this precise template can be used.

Comment: If you really want to use a specific template, you might be better of using something like `datatool` and storing each table in its own CSV file. Your table format could also be simplified (and made nicer) using `array` and `booktabs`.

Comment: See e.g. [Formatting complex table from CSV using datatool](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17618) and [Beautiful table samples](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112343)

Comment: what's the formula for Q ?

Answer (score 2):

`pgfplotstable` supports it. To this end, you define a new column type (I chose `L`) as in the following example.

Note that this would also try to format empty cells. To work around this limitation, I introduced a macro `\EMPTY` which disables the new column type by means of `\multicolumn{1}{r}{}`.

Here is your example. The only difference is the column type definition and the use of `\EMPTY` in your header row:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\EMPTY{\multicolumn{1}{r}{}}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]
    {>{\begin{pgfplotstablecoltype}[#1]}r<{\end{pgfplotstablecoltype}}}

    \begin{tabular}{l L{fixed,fixed zerofill} L{sci,sci zerofill} r r r l r r r L{fixed,precision=1,fixed zerofill} r}
    \hline
    \EMPTY&\EMPTY&\EMPTY&$n$&\EMPTY&\EMPTY&\EMPTY&\EMPTY&\EMPTY&$n$&\EMPTY&\EMPTY\\
    \cline{2-6}\cline{8-12}
    {}&1&2&3&4&5&{}&1&2&3&4&5\\
    \hline
$Q(n+0)$&1&1&2&3&3&$Q(n+100)$&48&54&54&50&60\\
$Q(n+5)$&4&5&5&6&6&$Q(n+105)$&52&54&58&60&53\\
$Q(n+10)$&6&8&8&8&10&$Q(n+110)$&60&60&52&62&66\\
$Q(n+15)$&9&10&11&11&12&$Q(n+115)$&55&62&68&62&58\\
$Q(n+20)$&12&12&12&16&14&$Q(n+120)$&72&58&61&78&57\\
$Q(n+25)$&14&16&16&16&16&$Q(n+125)$&71&68&64&63&73\\
$Q(n+30)$&20&17&17&20&21&$Q(n+130)$&63&71&72&72&80\\
$Q(n+35)$&19&20&22&21&22&$Q(n+135)$&61&71&77&65&80\\
$Q(n+40)$&23&23&24&24&24&$Q(n+140)$&71&69&77&75&73\\
$Q(n+45)$&24&24&32&24&25&$Q(n+145)$&77&79&76&80&79\\
$Q(n+50)$&30&28&26&30&30&$Q(n+150)$&75&82&77&80&80\\
$Q(n+55)$&28&32&30&32&32&$Q(n+155)$&78&83&83&78&85\\
$Q(n+60)$&32&32&40&33&31&$Q(n+160)$&82&85&84&84&88\\
$Q(n+65)$&38&35&33&39&40&$Q(n+165)$&83&87&88&87&86\\
$Q(n+70)$&37&38&40&39&40&$Q(n+170)$&90&88&87&92&90\\
$Q(n+75)$&39&42&40&41&43&$Q(n+175)$&91&92&92&94&92\\
$Q(n+80)$&44&43&43&46&44&$Q(n+180)$&93&94&94&96&94\\
$Q(n+85)$&45&47&47&46&48&$Q(n+185)$&96&96&96&96&96\\
$Q(n+90)$&48&48&48&48&48&$Q(n+190)$&96&128&72&96&115\\
$Q(n+95)$&64&41&52&54&56&$Q(n+195)$&100&84&114&110&93\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By the way: the next version (probably 1.10) of `pgfplotstable` will be able to cope with empty cell values automatically in this context.

Answer (score 1):

`Gnumeric` is itself powerful enough to build a template and convert it into `LaTeX` tabular
using concatenation of strings. Check out, for example, this `gnumeric-table.xml` 
created with `Gnumeric Spreadsheet 1.10.17`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gnm:Workbook xmlns:gnm="http://www.gnumeric.org/v10.dtd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.gnumeric.org/v9.xsd">
  <gnm:Version Epoch="1" Major="10" Minor="17" Full="1.10.17"/>
  <gnm:Attributes>
    <gnm:Attribute>
      <gnm:type>4</gnm:type>
      <gnm:name>WorkbookView::show_horizontal_scrollbar</gnm:name>
      <gnm:value>TRUE</gnm:value>
    </gnm:Attribute>
    <gnm:Attribute>
      <gnm:type>4</gnm:type>
      <gnm:name>WorkbookView::show_vertical_scrollbar</gnm:name>
      <gnm:value>TRUE</gnm:value>
    </gnm:Attribute>
    <gnm:Attribute>
      <gnm:type>4</gnm:type>
      <gnm:name>WorkbookView::show_notebook_tabs</gnm:name>
      <gnm:value>TRUE</gnm:value>
    </gnm:Attribute>
    <gnm:Attribute>
      <gnm:type>4</gnm:type>
      <gnm:name>WorkbookView::do_auto_completion</gnm:name>
      <gnm:value>TRUE</gnm:value>
    </gnm:Attribute>
    <gnm:Attribute>
      <gnm:type>4</gnm:type>
      <gnm:name>WorkbookView::is_protected</gnm:name>
      <gnm:value>FALSE</gnm:value>
    </gnm:Attribute>
  </gnm:Attributes>
  <office:document-meta xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0" xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office" office:version="1.2">
    <office:meta>
      <dc:date>2013-11-26T09:02:25Z</dc:date>
      <meta:creation-date>2013-11-26T06:36:22Z</meta:creation-date>
    </office:meta>
  </office:document-meta>
  <gnm:Calculation ManualRecalc="0" EnableIteration="1" MaxIterations="100" IterationTolerance="0.001" FloatRadix="2" FloatDigits="53"/>
  <gnm:SheetNameIndex>
    <gnm:SheetName gnm:Cols="256" gnm:Rows="65536">Sheet1</gnm:SheetName>
    <gnm:SheetName gnm:Cols="256" gnm:Rows="65536">Sheet3</gnm:SheetName>
  </gnm:SheetNameIndex>
  <gnm:Geometry Width="918" Height="365"/>
  <gnm:Sheets>
    <gnm:Sheet DisplayFormulas="0" HideZero="0" HideGrid="0" HideColHeader="0" HideRowHeader="0" DisplayOutlines="1" OutlineSymbolsBelow="1" OutlineSymbolsRight="1" Visibility="GNM_SHEET_VISIBILITY_VISIBLE" GridColor="0:0:0">
      <gnm:Name>Sheet1</gnm:Name>
      <gnm:MaxCol>14</gnm:MaxCol>
      <gnm:MaxRow>12</gnm:MaxRow>
      <gnm:Zoom>1</gnm:Zoom>
      <gnm:Names>
        <gnm:Name>
          <gnm:name>Print_Area</gnm:name>
          <gnm:value>#REF!</gnm:value>
          <gnm:position>A1</gnm:position>
        </gnm:Name>
        <gnm:Name>
          <gnm:name>Sheet_Title</gnm:name>
          <gnm:value>&quot;Sheet1&quot;</gnm:value>
          <gnm:position>A1</gnm:position>
        </gnm:Name>
      </gnm:Names>
      <gnm:PrintInformation>
        <gnm:Margins>
          <gnm:top Points="120" PrefUnit="mm"/>
          <gnm:bottom Points="120" PrefUnit="mm"/>
          <gnm:left Points="72" PrefUnit="mm"/>
          <gnm:right Points="72" PrefUnit="mm"/>
          <gnm:header Points="72" PrefUnit="mm"/>
          <gnm:footer Points="72" PrefUnit="mm"/>
        </gnm:Margins>
        <gnm:Scale type="percentage" percentage="100"/>
        <gnm:vcenter value="0"/>
        <gnm:hcenter value="0"/>
        <gnm:grid value="0"/>
        <gnm:even_if_only_styles value="0"/>
        <gnm:monochrome value="0"/>
        <gnm:draft value="0"/>
        <gnm:titles value="0"/>
        <gnm:do_not_print value="0"/>
        <gnm:print_range value="0"/>
        <gnm:order>d_then_r</gnm:order>
        <gnm:orientation>portrait</gnm:orientation>
        <gnm:Header Left="" Middle="&amp;[TAB]" Right=""/>
        <gnm:Footer Left="" Middle="Page &amp;[PAGE]" Right=""/>
        <gnm:paper>na_letter</gnm:paper>
        <gnm:comments>in_place</gnm:comments>
        <gnm:errors>as_displayed</gnm:errors>
      </gnm:PrintInformation>
      <gnm:Styles>
        <gnm:StyleRegion startCol="0" startRow="0" endCol="0" endRow="15">
          <gnm:Style HAlign="1" VAlign="2" WrapText="0" ShrinkToFit="0" Rotation="0" Shade="0" Indent="0" Locked="1" Hidden="0" Fore="0:0:0" Back="FFFF:FFFF:FFFF" PatternColor="0:0:0" Format="General">
            <gnm:Font Unit="10" Bold="0" Italic="0" Underline="0" StrikeThrough="0" Script="0">Sans</gnm:Font>
          </gnm:Style>
        </gnm:StyleRegion>
        <gnm:StyleRegion startCol="0" startRow="16" endCol="15" endRow="255">
          <gnm:Style HAlign="1" VAlign="2" WrapText="0" ShrinkToFit="0" Rotation="0" Shade="0" Indent="0" Locked="1" Hidden="0" Fore="0:0:0" Back="FFFF:FFFF:FFFF" PatternColor="0:0:0" Format="General">
            <gnm:Font Unit="10" Bold="0" Italic="0" Underline="0" StrikeThrough="0" Script="0">Sans</gnm:Font>
          </gnm:Style>
        </gnm:StyleRegion>
        <gnm:StyleRegion startCol="0" startRow="256" endCol="63" endRow="65535">
          <gnm:Style HAlign="1" VAlign="2" WrapText="0" ShrinkToFit="0" Rotation="0" Shade="0" Indent="0" Locked="1" Hidden="0" Fore="0:0:0" Back="FFFF:FFFF:FFFF" PatternColor="0:0:0" Format="General">
            <gnm:Font Unit="10" Bold="0" Italic="0" Underline="0" StrikeThrough="0" Script="0">Sans</gnm:Font>
          </gnm:Style>
        </gnm:StyleRegion>
        <gnm:StyleRegion startCol="1" startRow="0" endCol="13" endRow="6">
          <gnm:Style HAlign="1" VAlign="2" WrapText="0" ShrinkToFit="0" Rotation="0" Shade="0" Indent="0" Locked="1" Hidden="0" Fore="0:0:0" Back="FFFF:FFFF:FFFF" PatternColor="0:0:0" Format="General">
            <gnm:Font Unit="10" Bold="0" Italic="0" Underline="0" StrikeThrough="0" Script="0">Sans</gnm:Font>
          </gnm:Style>
        </gnm:StyleRegion>
        <gnm:StyleRegion startCol="1" startRow="7" endCol="12" endRow="9">
          <gnm:Style HAlign="1" VAlign="2" WrapText="0" ShrinkToFit="0" Rotation="0" Shade="0" Indent="0" Locked="1" Hidden="0" Fore="0:0:0" Back="FFFF:FFFF:FFFF" PatternColor="0:0:0" Format="General">
            <gnm:Font Unit="10" Bold="0" Italic="0" Underline="0" StrikeThrough="0" Script="0">Arial</gnm:Font>
          </gnm:Style>
        </gnm:StyleRegion>
        <gnm:StyleRegion startCol="1" startRow="10" endCol="12" endRow="15">
          <gnm:Style HAlign="1" VAlign="2" WrapText="0" ShrinkToFit="0" Rotation="0" Shade="0" Indent="0" Locked="1" Hidden="0" Fore="0:0:0" Back="FFFF:FFFF:FFFF" PatternColor="0:0:0" Format="General">
            <gnm:Font Unit="10" Bold="0" Italic="0" Underline="0" StrikeThrough="0" Script="0">Sans</gnm:Font>
          </gnm:Style>
        </gnm:StyleRegion>
        <gnm:StyleRegion startCol="13" startRow="7" endCol="13" endRow="8">
          <gnm:Style HAlign="1" VAlign="2" WrapText="0" ShrinkToFit="0" Rotation="0" Shade="0" Indent="0" Locked="1" Hidden="0" Fore="0:0:0" Back="FFFF:FFFF:FFFF" PatternColor="0:0:0" Format="General">
            <gnm:Font Unit="10" Bold="0" Italic="0" Underline="0" StrikeThrough="0" Script="0">Arial</gnm:Font>
          </gnm:Style>
        </gnm:StyleRegion>
        <gnm:StyleRegion startCol="13" startRow="9" endCol="13" endRow="15">
          <gnm:Style HAlign="1" VAlign="2" WrapText="0" ShrinkToFit="0" Rotation="0" Shade="0" Indent="0" Locked="1" Hidden="0" Fore="0:0:0" Back="FFFF:FFFF:FFFF" PatternColor="0:0:0" Format="General">
            <gnm:Font Unit="10" Bold="0" Italic="0" Underline="0" StrikeThrough="0" Script="0">Sans</gnm:Font>
          </gnm:Style>
        </gnm:StyleRegion>
        <gnm:StyleRegion startCol="14" startRow="0" endCol="14" endRow="2">
          <gnm:Style HAlign="1" VAlign="2" WrapText="0" ShrinkToFit="0" Rotation="0" Shade="0" Indent="0" Locked="1" Hidden="0" Fore="0:0:0" Back="FFFF:FFFF:FFFF" PatternColor="0:0:0" Format="General">
            <gnm:Font Unit="10" Bold="0" Italic="0" Underline="0" StrikeThrough="0" Script="0">Sans</gnm:Font>
          </gnm:Style>
        </gnm:StyleRegion>
        <gnm:StyleRegion startCol="14" startRow="3" endCol="14" endRow="5">
          <gnm:Style HAlign="1" VAlign="2" WrapText="0" ShrinkToFit="0" Rotation="0" Shade="0" Indent="0" Locked="1" Hidden="0" Fore="0:0:0" Back="FFFF:FFFF:FFFF" PatternColor="0:0:0" Format="General">
            <gnm:Font Unit="10" Bold="0" Italic="0" Underline="0" StrikeThrough="0" Script="0">Arial</gnm:Font>
          </gnm:Style>
        </gnm:StyleRegion>
        <gnm:StyleRegion startCol="14" startRow="6" endCol="14" endRow="6">
          <gnm:Style HAlign="1" VAlign="2" WrapText="0" ShrinkToFit="0" Rotation="0" Shade="0" Indent="0" Locked="1" Hidden="0" Fore="0:0:0" Back="FFFF:FFFF:FFFF" PatternColor="0:0:0" Format="General">
            <gnm:Font Unit="10" Bold="0" Italic="0" Underline="0" StrikeThrough="0" Script="0">Sans</gnm:Font>
          </gnm:Style>
        </gnm:StyleRegion>
        <gnm:StyleRegion startCol="14" startRow="7" endCol="14" endRow="9">
          <gnm:Style HAlign="1" VAlign="2" WrapText="0" ShrinkToFit="0" Rotation="0" Shade="0" Indent="0" Locked="1" Hidden="0" Fore="0:0:0" Back="FFFF:FFFF:FFFF" PatternColor="0:0:0" Format="General">
            <gnm:Font Unit="10" Bold="0" Italic="0" Underline="0" StrikeThrough="0" Script="0">Arial</gnm:Font>
          </gnm:Style>
        </gnm:StyleRegion>
        <gnm:StyleRegion startCol="14" startRow="10" endCol="14" endRow="15">
          <gnm:Style HAlign="1" VAlign="2" WrapText="0" ShrinkToFit="0" Rotation="0" Shade="0" Indent="0" Locked="1" Hidden="0" Fore="0:0:0" Back="FFFF:FFFF:FFFF" PatternColor="0:0:0" Format="General">
            <gnm:Font Unit="10" Bold="0" Italic="0" Underline="0" StrikeThrough="0" Script="0">Sans</gnm:Font>
          </gnm:Style>
        </gnm:StyleRegion>
        <gnm:StyleRegion startCol="15" startRow="0" endCol="15" endRow="15">
          <gnm:Style HAlign="1" VAlign="2" WrapText="0" ShrinkToFit="0" Rotation="0" Shade="0" Indent="0" Locked="1" Hidden="0" Fore="0:0:0" Back="FFFF:FFFF:FFFF" PatternColor="0:0:0" Format="General">
            <gnm:Font Unit="10" Bold="0" Italic="0" Underline="0" StrikeThrough="0" Script="0">Sans</gnm:Font>
          </gnm:Style>
        </gnm:StyleRegion>
        <gnm:StyleRegion startCol="16" startRow="0" endCol="63" endRow="255">
          <gnm:Style HAlign="1" VAlign="2" WrapText="0" ShrinkToFit="0" Rotation="0" Shade="0" Indent="0" Locked="1" Hidden="0" Fore="0:0:0" Back="FFFF:FFFF:FFFF" PatternColor="0:0:0" Format="General">
            <gnm:Font Unit="10" Bold="0" Italic="0" Underline="0" StrikeThrough="0" Script="0">Sans</gnm:Font>
          </gnm:Style>
        </gnm:StyleRegion>
        <gnm:StyleRegion startCol="64" startRow="0" endCol="255" endRow="65535">
          <gnm:Style HAlign="1" VAlign="2" WrapText="0" ShrinkToFit="0" Rotation="0" Shade="0" Indent="0" Locked="1" Hidden="0" Fore="0:0:0" Back="FFFF:FFFF:FFFF" PatternColor="0:0:0" Format="General">
            <gnm:Font Unit="10" Bold="0" Italic="0" Underline="0" StrikeThrough="0" Script="0">Sans</gnm:Font>
          </gnm:Style>
        </gnm:StyleRegion>
      </gnm:Styles>
      <gnm:Cols DefaultSizePts="48">
        <gnm:ColInfo No="0" Unit="48" Count="2"/>
        <gnm:ColInfo No="2" Unit="15.75" Count="2"/>
        <gnm:ColInfo No="4" Unit="21.75"/>
        <gnm:ColInfo No="5" Unit="15.75"/>
        <gnm:ColInfo No="6" Unit="14.25"/>
        <gnm:ColInfo No="7" Unit="54.75"/>
        <gnm:ColInfo No="8" Unit="15.75" Count="2"/>
        <gnm:ColInfo No="10" Unit="21.75"/>
        <gnm:ColInfo No="11" Unit="15.75" Count="2"/>
        <gnm:ColInfo No="13" Unit="19.5" HardSize="1"/>
        <gnm:ColInfo No="14" Unit="267"/>
      </gnm:Cols>
      <gnm:Rows DefaultSizePts="12.75">
        <gnm:RowInfo No="0" Unit="12.75" Count="12"/>
      </gnm:Rows>
      <gnm:Selections CursorCol="12" CursorRow="13">
        <gnm:Selection startCol="12" startRow="13" endCol="12" endRow="13"/>
      </gnm:Selections>
      <gnm:Cells>
        <gnm:Cell Row="0" Col="5" ValueType="10"></gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="1" Col="1" ValueType="60">l</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="1" Col="2" ValueType="60">r</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="1" Col="3" ValueType="60">r</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="1" Col="4" ValueType="60">r</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="1" Col="5" ValueType="60">r</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="1" Col="6" ValueType="60">r</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="1" Col="7" ValueType="60">l</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="1" Col="8" ValueType="60">r</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="1" Col="9" ValueType="60">r</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="1" Col="10" ValueType="60">r</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="1" Col="11" ValueType="60">r</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="1" Col="12" ValueType="60">r</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="1" Col="14">=&quot;\\begin{tabular}{&quot;&amp;concatenate($B$2:$M$2)&amp;&quot;}&quot;</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="2" Col="14" ValueType="60">\hline</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="1" ValueType="60">{}</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="2" ValueType="60">{}</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="3" ValueType="60">{}</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="4" ValueType="60">$n$</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="5" ValueType="60">{}</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="6" ValueType="60">{}</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="7" ValueType="60">{}</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="8" ValueType="60">{}</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="9" ValueType="60">{}</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="10" ValueType="60">$n$</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="11" ValueType="60">{}</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="12" ValueType="60">{}</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="14" Rows="1" Cols="1">=B4&amp;concatenate(&quot;&amp;&quot;&amp;C4:M4)&amp;&quot; \\\\&quot;</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="4" Col="14" ValueType="60"> \cline{2-6}\cline{8-12}</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="5" Col="1" ValueType="60">{}</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="5" Col="2" ValueType="40">1</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="5" Col="3" ValueType="40">2</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="5" Col="4" ValueType="40">3</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="5" Col="5" ValueType="40">4</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="5" Col="6" ValueType="40">5</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="5" Col="7" ValueType="60">{}</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="5" Col="8" ValueType="40">1</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="5" Col="9" ValueType="40">2</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="5" Col="10" ValueType="40">3</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="5" Col="11" ValueType="40">4</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="5" Col="12" ValueType="40">5</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="5" Col="14" Rows="1" Cols="1">=B6&amp;concatenate(&quot;&amp;&quot;&amp;C6:M6)&amp;&quot; \\\\&quot;</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="6" Col="14" ValueType="60">\hline</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="7" Col="0" ValueType="40">0</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="7" Col="1" ExprID="1">=&quot;$Q(n+&quot;&amp;A8&amp;&quot;)$&quot;</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="7" Col="2" ValueType="40">1</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="7" Col="3" ValueType="40">1</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="7" Col="4" ValueType="40">2</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="7" Col="5" ValueType="40">3</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="7" Col="6" ValueType="40">3</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="7" Col="7" ExprID="2">=&quot;$Q(n+&quot;&amp;A8+100&amp;&quot;)$&quot;</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="7" Col="8" ValueType="40">48</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="7" Col="9" ValueType="40">54</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="7" Col="10" ValueType="40">54</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="7" Col="11" ValueType="40">50</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="7" Col="12" ValueType="40">60</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="7" Col="14" Rows="1" Cols="1">=B8&amp;concatenate(&quot;&amp;&quot;&amp;C8:M8)&amp;&quot; \\\\&quot;</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="8" Col="0" ExprID="3">=A8+5</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="8" Col="1" ExprID="1"/>
        <gnm:Cell Row="8" Col="2" ValueType="40">4</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="8" Col="3" ValueType="40">5</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="8" Col="4" ValueType="40">5</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="8" Col="5" ValueType="40">6</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="8" Col="6" ValueType="40">6</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="8" Col="7" ExprID="2"/>
        <gnm:Cell Row="8" Col="8" ValueType="40">52</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="8" Col="9" ValueType="40">54</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="8" Col="10" ValueType="40">58</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="8" Col="11" ValueType="40">60</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="8" Col="12" ValueType="40">53</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="8" Col="14" Rows="1" Cols="1">=B9&amp;concatenate(&quot;&amp;&quot;&amp;C9:M9)&amp;&quot; \\\\&quot;</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="9" Col="0" ExprID="3"/>
        <gnm:Cell Row="9" Col="1" ExprID="1"/>
        <gnm:Cell Row="9" Col="2" ValueType="40">6</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="9" Col="3" ValueType="40">8</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="9" Col="4" ValueType="40">8</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="9" Col="5" ValueType="40">8</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="9" Col="6" ValueType="40">10</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="9" Col="7" ExprID="2"/>
        <gnm:Cell Row="9" Col="8" ValueType="40">60</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="9" Col="9" ValueType="40">60</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="9" Col="10" ValueType="40">52</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="9" Col="11" ValueType="40">62</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="9" Col="12" ValueType="40">66</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="9" Col="14" Rows="1" Cols="1">=B10&amp;concatenate(&quot;&amp;&quot;&amp;C10:M10)&amp;&quot; \\\\&quot;</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="11" Col="14" ValueType="60">\hline</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="12" Col="14" ValueType="60">\end{tabular}</gnm:Cell>
      </gnm:Cells>
      <gnm:SheetLayout TopLeft="A1"/>
      <gnm:Solver ModelType="0" ProblemType="0" MaxTime="60" MaxIter="1000" NonNeg="1" Discr="0" AutoScale="0" ProgramR="0"/>
    </gnm:Sheet>
    <gnm:Sheet DisplayFormulas="0" HideZero="0" HideGrid="0" HideColHeader="0" HideRowHeader="0" DisplayOutlines="1" OutlineSymbolsBelow="1" OutlineSymbolsRight="1" Visibility="GNM_SHEET_VISIBILITY_VISIBLE" GridColor="0:0:0">
      <gnm:Name>Sheet3</gnm:Name>
      <gnm:MaxCol>14</gnm:MaxCol>
      <gnm:MaxRow>7</gnm:MaxRow>
      <gnm:Zoom>1</gnm:Zoom>
      <gnm:Names>
        <gnm:Name>
          <gnm:name>Print_Area</gnm:name>
          <gnm:value>#REF!</gnm:value>
          <gnm:position>A1</gnm:position>
        </gnm:Name>
        <gnm:Name>
          <gnm:name>Sheet_Title</gnm:name>
          <gnm:value>&quot;Sheet3&quot;</gnm:value>
          <gnm:position>A1</gnm:position>
        </gnm:Name>
      </gnm:Names>
      <gnm:PrintInformation>
        <gnm:Margins>
          <gnm:top Points="120" PrefUnit="mm"/>
          <gnm:bottom Points="120" PrefUnit="mm"/>
          <gnm:left Points="72" PrefUnit="mm"/>
          <gnm:right Points="72" PrefUnit="mm"/>
          <gnm:header Points="72" PrefUnit="mm"/>
          <gnm:footer Points="72" PrefUnit="mm"/>
        </gnm:Margins>
        <gnm:Scale type="percentage" percentage="100"/>
        <gnm:vcenter value="0"/>
        <gnm:hcenter value="0"/>
        <gnm:grid value="0"/>
        <gnm:even_if_only_styles value="0"/>
        <gnm:monochrome value="0"/>
        <gnm:draft value="0"/>
        <gnm:titles value="0"/>
        <gnm:do_not_print value="0"/>
        <gnm:print_range value="0"/>
        <gnm:order>d_then_r</gnm:order>
        <gnm:orientation>portrait</gnm:orientation>
        <gnm:Header Left="" Middle="&amp;[TAB]" Right=""/>
        <gnm:Footer Left="" Middle="Page &amp;[PAGE]" Right=""/>
        <gnm:paper>na_letter</gnm:paper>
        <gnm:comments>in_place</gnm:comments>
        <gnm:errors>as_displayed</gnm:errors>
      </gnm:PrintInformation>
      <gnm:Styles>
        <gnm:StyleRegion startCol="0" startRow="0" endCol="255" endRow="65535">
          <gnm:Style HAlign="1" VAlign="2" WrapText="0" ShrinkToFit="0" Rotation="0" Shade="0" Indent="0" Locked="1" Hidden="0" Fore="0:0:0" Back="FFFF:FFFF:FFFF" PatternColor="0:0:0" Format="General">
            <gnm:Font Unit="10" Bold="0" Italic="0" Underline="0" StrikeThrough="0" Script="0">Sans</gnm:Font>
          </gnm:Style>
        </gnm:StyleRegion>
      </gnm:Styles>
      <gnm:Cols DefaultSizePts="48">
        <gnm:ColInfo No="1" Unit="48" Count="14"/>
      </gnm:Cols>
      <gnm:Rows DefaultSizePts="12.75">
        <gnm:RowInfo No="3" Unit="12.75" Count="5"/>
      </gnm:Rows>
      <gnm:Selections CursorCol="2" CursorRow="7">
        <gnm:Selection startCol="2" startRow="7" endCol="2" endRow="7"/>
      </gnm:Selections>
      <gnm:Cells>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="1" ValueType="60">{}</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="2" ValueType="60">{}</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="3" ValueType="60">{}</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="4" ValueType="60">$n$</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="5" ValueType="60">{}</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="6" ValueType="60">{}</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="7" ValueType="60">{}</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="8" ValueType="60">{}</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="9" ValueType="60">{}</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="10" ValueType="60">$n$</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="11" ValueType="60">{}</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="12" ValueType="60">{}</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="3" Col="14" Rows="1" Cols="1">=B4&amp;concatenate(&quot;&amp;&quot;&amp;C4:M4)&amp;&quot; \\\\&quot;</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="4" Col="1" ExprID="4">=A5+1</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="4" Col="2" ExprID="4"/>
        <gnm:Cell Row="4" Col="3" ExprID="4"/>
        <gnm:Cell Row="4" Col="4" ExprID="4"/>
        <gnm:Cell Row="4" Col="5" ExprID="4"/>
        <gnm:Cell Row="4" Col="6" ExprID="4"/>
        <gnm:Cell Row="4" Col="7" ExprID="4"/>
        <gnm:Cell Row="4" Col="8" ExprID="4"/>
        <gnm:Cell Row="4" Col="9" ExprID="4"/>
        <gnm:Cell Row="4" Col="10" ExprID="4"/>
        <gnm:Cell Row="4" Col="11" ExprID="4"/>
        <gnm:Cell Row="4" Col="12" ExprID="4"/>
        <gnm:Cell Row="6" Col="2" Rows="1" Cols="1">=B4&amp;concatenate(&quot;&amp;&quot;&amp;C4:M4)</gnm:Cell>
        <gnm:Cell Row="7" Col="2" Rows="1" Cols="1">=B5&amp;concatenate(&quot;&amp;&quot;&amp;C5:M5)</gnm:Cell>
      </gnm:Cells>
      <gnm:SheetLayout TopLeft="A1"/>
      <gnm:Solver ModelType="0" ProblemType="0" MaxTime="60" MaxIter="1000" NonNeg="1" Discr="0" AutoScale="0" ProgramR="0"/>
    </gnm:Sheet>
  </gnm:Sheets>
  <gnm:UIData SelectedTab="0"/>
</gnm:Workbook>
```

Columns from `B` to `M` are used to fill with the data,
columns `B` and `H` contains formulas `="$Q(n+"&A8&")$"` and `="$Q(n+"&A8+100&")$"`,
the column `O` contains the `LaTeX` tabular. To extens the table, 
just copy the last line down and fill it with data.

[image]

Complete `MWE` with `LaTeX` tabular data copied from the column `O` from `gnumeric-table.xml` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrlrrrrr}
\hline
{}&{}&{}&$n$&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&$n$&{}&{} \\
 \cline{2-6}\cline{8-12}
{}&1&2&3&4&5&{}&1&2&3&4&5 \\
\hline
$Q(n+0)$&1&1&2&3&3&$Q(n+100)$&48&54&54&50&60 \\
$Q(n+5)$&4&5&5&6&6&$Q(n+105)$&52&54&58&60&53 \\
$Q(n+10)$&6&8&8&8&10&$Q(n+110)$&60&60&52&62&66 \\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option will be to use the [calculator](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/calculator/) package, combined with [supertabular](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/supertabular) package to split the table over multipage.
Check [my previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108455/how-to-generate-a-table-of-trigonometric-functions-that-can-be-broken-across-pag/108458#108458) for an example on how to combine both of them to automate systematic and complex table generations.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually one way to copy your whole tables from Excel and give the format you want, it's a complement called [Excel2LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex/). You can design your table and write its content inside Excel and then just select the cells you want to convert into LaTeX code. Perhaps you'll need to modify a little the code generated to fit your needs (if you use subscripts, greek letters, etc.)

You'll also need to use the `booktabs` package `\usepackage{booktabs}`