# How can I center *and* decimal-align a PGFPlots table?

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

Here is the code I am working with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{measurements.dat}
sample num-bugs num-part other-measure another
   5       80      190        200        210
  15      520      410        430        350
  25      650      640        630        900
  35     1100     1200       1150       1020
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable, booktabs, colortbl}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\pgfplotstableset{
  every head row/.style=
    {before row={\toprule},
     after row={\midrule}},
  every last row/.style=
    {after row={\bottomrule}},
  every even row/.style=
    {before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}},
  columns/.style=
    {dec sep align,
    %column type=c
    }
  }

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  columns={sample, another, num-part},
  columns/sample/.style={
    column name={Sample},
  }
  ]{measurements.dat}
\end{document}
```

This results in the data being aligned at the decimal as expected.
However, the data is also aligned at `l`.
I need it to be aligned at `c`, so I add the option

```
columns/.style={column type=c}
```

(as commented-out above).

This generates the error:

```
ERROR: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.

--- TeX said ---
<template> \endtemplate 

l.31   ]{measurements.dat}

--- HELP ---
There are too many separate items (column entries) in a single row of
an array or tabular environment. In other words, there were too many &
's before the end of the row. You probably forgot the \\ at the end of
the preceding row.
```

How can I effect a centered *and* aligned column?

---

#### Example

```
Header1 Header2 LongerHeader3 HeaderWithoutARealName4
  1.0     2.0        3.0                    4.0
  2.0    13.0        4             1234567890.23
```

---

#### Current left aligned outcome

[image]

Comment: To be picky is it the thousands sep not the decimal alignment you are asking for?

Comment: @percusse I'm looking for centered alignment at the decimal point, but aligning the thousands sep as well would be a *definite* plus.  See my edit.

Comment: I think I still don't get it. Where should the centerline hit in your first example?

Comment: @percusse Each column should be centered relative to the longest (width-wise) item in the column (note that this could be data *or* the header), and each centered piece of data should also align with the others at its decimal point.

Comment: The `dec sep align` introduces two columns, one right-aligned, the other one left-aligned. And in fact, the decimal point is center-aligned (you just don’t have any decimals in your numbers). The `dec sep align` key/algorithm is not very flexible. I would go with a `siunitx` solution here, too. You may need to tell PGFmath/plotstable to not typeset numbers but leave them alone so that `siunitx` can parse them, see [an answer of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108459/16595) that uses `siunitx` and `pgfplotstable` (look out for `string type`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would that work for you?  It uses `siunitx` to format the columns. There seems to some issues between the `siunitx` and `pgfplotstable`, therefore each column has to be formatted separatly and a column name has to be provided in braces. If not, siunitx complains about each *e* in the column name. Maybe some of the wizards here, know how to solve that.

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{measurements.dat}
sample num-bugs num-part other-measure another
   5       80      190        200        210.02
  15      520      410.00     430        350
  25      650      640        630.2      900
  35     1100     1200        1150       1020
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable, booktabs, colortbl, siunitx, array}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    assign column name/.code=\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/column name}{{{#1}}},
  columns={sample, another, num-part},
    every head row/.style=
    {before row={\toprule},
     after row={\midrule}},
  every last row/.style=
    {after row={\bottomrule}},
  every even row/.style=
    {before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}},
  columns/sample/.style={
   assign column name={Sample}, 
    column type={S[]}, string type,
  },
    columns/another/.style={%
        assign column name={Another},
        column type={S[]}, string type,
   }, 
        columns/num-part/.style={%
        assign column name={Num-Part},
        column type={S[]}, string type,
   },
    % Does produce the desired effect
    % columns/.style={column type={S[]}, string type,},
  ]{measurements.dat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look at the `multicolumn names` key for the problem with `\multicolumn`. Also `siunitx` does not parse a cell if its content is surrounded by braces (but that gets tricky to set up because `{ }` will be removed internally a few times). But you can use `assign column name/.code=\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/column name}{{{#1}}},` and then use `assign column name` instead of `column name` for every column without the need for any braces (in the main input) and `\multicolumn`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel thanks for the advice, the code looks cleaner now. I did I just wonder why the columns/.style key does not have any effect. Maybe you happen to have another hint? Also I didn't quite understand what you meant with the multicolumn names key.