# How to make this table automatically?

Tags: tables

I want to make this table automaticly. That is mean, I receive the value of $\sin$, $\cos$, $\tan$ and $\cot$ of the angle $\alpha$ without typesetting by hand. But I don't know. [image]

How can I make it?

Note. The words "Không xác định" means undefined.

Comment: What do you mean with "automaticly"?

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\def\getNum#1\relax{\gdef\num{#1}$\tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{#1}$}

\def\getDenum#1\\{\gdef\denum{#1}$\tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{#1}$&$\sqrt{\tfrac{\num}{\denum}}$\\}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}
{
    >{$}c<{^\circ$}
    >{\getNum}c
    >{\getDenum}c
    c
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\theta$}&
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\sin\theta$}&
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\cos\theta$}&
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\tan\theta$}\\
\midrule
0&
    0&
        4\\
30&
    1&
        3\\
45&
    2&
        2\\
60&
    3&
        1\\
90&
    4&
        0\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you might be looking for this question: [How to generate a table of trigonometric functions that can be broken across pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108455/19356).

Comment: The angles in the question are in radians, not degrees.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: Oh it is not a big issue. :-)

Comment: @PSTikZ Cool, didn't know this "0, 1, 2, 3, 4-Trick" yet. That's easy to remember.