# How to alternately shade rows in a table

Tags: tables, color, shading

I'm having trouble finding anything that will work with this checklist table that I have set up. I was hoping someone might have some suggestions.

```
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{center}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}%
\begin{tabular}{ | m{5cm} | c | l | l |l |l |l |}
\hline
Checklist & Agency #1 & Agency #2 & Agency #3 & Agency #4 &  Agency #5 \\ \hline
List Item. & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} \\ 
\hline
List Item. & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} \\ 
\hline
List Item. & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} \\
\hline
List Item. & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} \\
\hline
List Item. & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} \\
\hline
List Item. & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Have a look at the solutions [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33758/professional-looking-tables-with-alternating-row-colors).  Let us know if they help at all.

Comment: See also [here](http://texblog.org/2011/09/02/coloring-every-alternate-table-row/)

Comment: @Xavier it's a duplicate of that _if_ you know that neither `longtable` nor `LyX` that appear in the title are relevant to the answer, but I think it's reasonable not to know that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Agree. I didn't mean my close vote / comment to be offensive; I just though this question must have been asked before and found the one above. Should we edit the title of the linked one to make it more generic, or make this question the reference one?

Comment: @Xavier not sure, one of those things:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

`xcolor` provides some convenient extras over `colortbl`. But please always post *complete* documents and check for unrelated errors (extra `{` and use of `#` in this case)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}



\begin{center}
\rowcolors{2}{red}{yellow}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}%
\begin{tabular}{ | m{5cm} | c | l | l |l |l |l |}
\hline
Checklist & Agency \#1 & Agency \#2 & Agency \#3 & Agency \#4 &  Agency \#5 \\ \hline
List Item. & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} \\ 
\hline
List Item. & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} \\ 
\hline
List Item. & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} \\
\hline
List Item. & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} \\
\hline
List Item. & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} \\
\hline
List Item. & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} & \hspace{1.3 cm} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```