# Alternatingly shading rows with @{}

Tags: tables, color, shading

I want to alternately shade the rows in my table. I am aware of [How to alternately shade rows in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116603/how-to-alternately-shade-rows-in-a-table) and similar questions. However, as my table is long and needs to be aligned very neatly in order to not be totally confusion, I make heavy use of the self-defined delimiters for cells via `@{}`. The formatting gets totally screwed when I try the solutions proposed elsewhere. I suppose the `@{}` is what trips up `\rowcolors`. How can I color the rows without screwing up the formatting?

A minimal example with my table is

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!15} % <--- this is the solution from the other questions

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}    {cl@{}r@{\,}r@{\,}r@{\,}r@{\,}r@{}l@{\qquad}l@{}r@{\,}r@{\,}r@{\,}r@{}lc@{\qquad}l@{}r@{\,}r@{)(}r@{}llc}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{7}{c}{\(SO(10)\) }  & \multicolumn{7}{c}{\(SU(5)\)} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\(\mathcal G_\mathrm{SM}\)} & \\
Level & \multicolumn{7}{c}{weight} & \multicolumn{6}{l}{weight} & \(\mathrm{IR}_x\) & \multicolumn{5}{c}{weight} & \(\mathrm{IR}_Y\) & SM state \\ \midrule
0 & (&0& 0& 0& 0& 1&) & (&0& 1& 0& 0&) & \(\mathbf{10}_1\) &        (&1&0&1&) & \(\mathbf{3} \times \mathbf{2}_\frac{1}{6}\)&\(u_l\)\\
1 & (&0& 0& 1& 0& -1&) & (&0& 0& 0& 1&) & \(\overline{\mathbf 5}_{-3}\) &   (&0&1&0&) & \(\overline{\mathbf{3}} \times \mathbf 1_\frac{1}{3}\) & \(d^c_r\)\\
2 & (&0& 1& -1& 1& 0&) & (&1& -1& 1& 0&) & \(\mathbf{10}_1\) &      (&0&1&0&) & \(\overline{\mathbf{3}} \times \mathbf 1_{-\frac{2}{3}}\)& \(u^c_r\)\\
3 & (&1& -1& 0& 1& 0&) & (&0& 0& 1& -1&) & \(\overline{\mathbf 5}_{-3}\) &  (&0&0&1&) & \(\mathbf{1} \times \mathbf 2_{-\frac{1}{2}}\) &\(\nu_l\)\\
3 & (&0& 1& 0& -1& 0&) & (&1& 0& -1& 1&) & \(\mathbf{10}_1\) &      (&1&0&-1&) & \(\mathbf{3} \times \mathbf{2}_{\frac{1}{6}}\) &\(d_l\)\\
4 & (&-1& 0& 0& 1& 0&) & (&-1& 0& 1&0&) & \(\mathbf{10}_1\) &       (&-1&1&1&) & \(\mathbf{3} \times \mathbf{2}_{\frac{1}{6}}\) &\(u_l\)\\
4 & (&1& -1& 1& -1& 0&) & (&0& 1& -1& 0&) & \(\overline{\mathbf 5}_{-3}\) &     (&1&-1&0&) & \(\overline{\mathbf{3}} \times \mathbf{1}_\frac{1}{3}\) &\(d^c_r\)\\
5 & (&-1& 0& 1& -1& 0&) & (&-1& 1& -1& 1&) & \(\mathbf{10}_1\) &        (&0&0&0&) & \(\mathbf{1} \times \mathbf{1}_1\) &\(e^c_r\)\\
5 & (&1& 0& -1& 0& 1&) & (&1& 0& 0& -1&) & \(\mathbf{10}_1\) &      (&1&-1&0&) & \(\overline{\mathbf{3}} \times \mathbf{1}_{-\frac{2}{3}}\)& \(u^c_r\)\\
6 & (&-1& 1& -1& 0& 1&) & (&0& 0& 0& 0&) & \(\mathbf 1_5\) &        (&0&0&0&) & \(\mathbf 1 \times \mathbf 1_0\) &\(\nu_r\)\\
6 & (&1& 0& 0& 0& -1&) & (&1& -1& 0& 0&) & \(\overline{\mathbf 5}_{-3}\) &  (&0&0&-1&) & \(\mathbf 1 \times \mathbf 2_{-\frac{1}{2}}\) &\(e_l\)\\
7 & (&0& -1& 0& 0& 1&) & (&-1& 1& 0& -1&) & \(\mathbf{10}_1\) &         (&0&-1&1&) & \(\mathbf 3 \times \mathbf 2_\frac{1}{6}\) & \(u_l\)\\
7 & (&-1& 1& 0& 0& -1&) & (&0& -1& 0& 1&) & \(\mathbf{10}_1\) &         (&-1&1&-1&) & \(\mathbf{3} \times \mathbf 2_\frac{1}{6}\) &\(d_l\)\\
8 & (&0& -1& 1& 0& -1&) & (&-1& 0& 0& 0&) & \(\overline{\mathbf 5}_{-3}\) &     (&-1&0&0&) & \(\overline{\mathbf{3}} \times \mathbf{1}_\frac{1}{3}\) &\(d^c_r\)\\
9 & (&0& 0& -1& 1& 0&) & (&0& -1& 1& -1&) & \(\mathbf{10}_1\) &         (&-1&0&0&) & \(\overline{\mathbf{3}}\times \mathbf{1}_{-\frac{2}{3}}\) &\(u^c_r\)\\
10 & (&0& 0& 0& -1& 0&) & (&0& 0& -1& 0&) & \(\mathbf{10}_1\) &         (&0&-1&-1&) & \(\mathbf{3} \times \mathbf 2_\frac{1}{6}\)& \(d_l\)\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that might work for you.  It uses the package `pgffor`.  I've only partially implemented it:  there's a lot to rewrite in your code.  But I think it achieves the effect that you want.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\nnkweights}[1]{(\foreach \x in {#1} {\makebox[1.15em][r]{\x}})}
\begin{document}

\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!15} % <--- this is the solution from the other questions

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}    {c c  c  l c  c  c} \toprule
      & {\(SO(10)\) }  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\(SU(5)\)}    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\(\mathcal G_\mathrm{SM}\)} &          \\\cmidrule(rl){3-4}\cmidrule(rl){5-6}
Level & {weight}       & {weight}    & \(\mathrm{IR}_x\)  & {weight} & \(\mathrm{IR}_Y\)                   & SM state \\ \midrule
0 & \nnkweights{  0, 0, 0, 0, 1}  & \nnkweights{ 0, 1, 0, 0}  & \(\mathbf{10}_1\)             & \nnkweights{ 1, 0}\nnkweights{  1} & \(\mathbf{3} \times \mathbf{2}_\frac{1}{6}\)              & \(u_l\)  \\
1 & \nnkweights{  0, 0, 1, 0,-1}  & \nnkweights{ 0, 0, 0, 1}  & \(\overline{\mathbf 5}_{-3}\) & \nnkweights{ 0, 1}\nnkweights{  0} & \(\overline{\mathbf{3}} \times \mathbf 1_\frac{1}{3}\)    & \(d^c_r\)\\
2 & \nnkweights{  0, 1, -1, 1, 0} & \nnkweights{ 1, -1, 1, 0} & \(\mathbf{10}_1\)             & \nnkweights{ 0, 1}\nnkweights{  0} & \(\overline{\mathbf{3}} \times \mathbf 1_{-\frac{2}{3}}\) & \(u^c_r\)\\
3 & \nnkweights{  1, -1, 0, 1, 0} & \nnkweights{ 0, 0, 1,-1}  & \(\overline{\mathbf 5}_{-3}\) & \nnkweights{ 0, 0}\nnkweights{  1} & \(\mathbf{1} \times \mathbf 2_{-\frac{1}{2}}\)            & \(\nu_l\)\\
3 & \nnkweights{  0, 1, 0, -1, 0} & \nnkweights{ 1, 0, -1, 1} & \(\mathbf{10}_1\)             & \nnkweights{ 1, 0}\nnkweights{ -1} & \(\mathbf{3} \times \mathbf{2}_{\frac{1}{6}}\)            & \(d_l\)  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I'm made a few additional changes:  I got rid of the `\qquad`s  and I've added some `\cmidrule`s.  I might suggest putting the content of the `\makebox`es in math-mode so that the negative sign is type-set correctly, but I've not implemented that change.

Regarding `\qquad`, if you really want the extra space in your document, I would suggest adding a dummy column and adding the appropriate white space via `\rule{<dim>}{0pt}` in its first occurrence.  If you're particularly finicky about the space then you can do something like `\rule{\dimexpr<desired-dimension>-2\tabcolsep\relax}{0pt}`.  Otherwise, the alternate row shading apparently doesn't like handling `@{<detail>}`.

Finally, I would suggest changing

```
\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!15}
```

to

```
\rowcolors{5}{white}{gray!15}
```

to get the coloring out of your header.  The row specification seems a bit off, but that's because the `\cmidrule`s are fooling `xcolor` into thinking there are extra rows added to the table.

Having done this, the result will be

[image]