# How do I expand exactly once a macro which takes an argument

Tags: expansion

I thought I was finally understanding expansion, but then I wrote something along the following lines, and it has me a bit stumped.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\def\ae@test#1{\textcolor{red}{\fbox{#1}}}
\edef\aetest#1{<a bunch of expandable material>\expandonce\ae@test{#1}<more expandable material>}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\aetest{Hello}

\end{document}
```

I suspect the issue has something to do with the need to look ahead for the arguments, but I don't even know how to test that theory.

So, I have two questions:

- What's actually happening that the expansion isn't working as I would like to think it should?
- How do I write my macro `\aetest` so that it does what I want?  Namely,

  ```
  \aetest{<arg>}->\textcolor{red}{\fbox{<arg>}}
  ```

I suppose there might be some trick I could do using tokens (since tokens within an `\edef` expand just once), but I'm a bit cloudy on that approach since I haven't played much with tokens.

Incidentally, I wrote `\ae@test` as I did because I'm not interested in the following sort of scenario:

```
\def\ae@test#1{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
```

where with `\aetest` the following would accomplish what I want

```
\edef\aetest#1{\expandafter\noexpand\ae@test{#1}}
```

The issue is that I want to expand a macro which may have several fragile elements within it.

I did try something along the following lines

```
\edef\aetest#1{\unexpanded\expandafter{\ae@test{#1}}}
```

thinking that `\ae@test` would thus be able to grab its argument, but still the same issue.

Comment: Did you solve the issue already in your pdfkeys solution elsewhere?

Comment: @1010011010 Not quite.  I mean the answers here work.  In particular, I've been contemplating asking another question about wipet's solution.  But right now I'm trying to figure out what actually works for me.

Comment: I'll get into `pgfkeys` and see if I can get something to work. I'm quite interested in this myself. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `#` gets doubled inside `\unexpanded`. A workaround with `\expandafter`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter

\def\ae@test#1{\textcolor{red}{\fbox{#1}}}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\aetest\expandafter#\expandafter1\expandafter{%
  \ae@test{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \aetest{Hello}
\end{document}
```

Then `\aetest` has the following definition:

```
macro:#1->\textcolor {red}{\fbox {#1}}
```

Of course in this case, a simple `\let` would be easier to get the same meaning:

```
\let\aetest\ae@test
```

---

A quite complex way is to replace `#1` by a different token and exchange it afterwards:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\def\ae@test#1{\textcolor{red}{\fbox{#1}}}
\let\myarg\relax
\edef\aetest#1{\expandonce{\ae@test{\myarg/}}}
\patchcmd\aetest{\myarg/}{#1}{}{%
  \errmessage{Patching \noexpand\aetest failed}%
}
```

The last step needs to be repeated to the number of occurrences of `#1` inside the definition text of `\ae@test`. If the number is unknown, then
a loop can be used, which aborts at the first error:

```
\let\myarg\relax
\edef\aetest#1{\expandonce{\ae@test{\myarg/}}}
\count@=\@ne
\@whilenum\count@>\z@\do{%
  \edef\process@me{%
    \noexpand\patchcmd\noexpand\aetest{\noexpand\myarg/}{\string#1}%
  }\process@me{}{\count@=\z@}%
}
```

Scratch counter `\count@` signalizes the success of the patching. If it is set to one, then the replacement of `\myarg` to `#1` is tried. If the patching failed, because `\myarg` could not be found anymore, then `\count@` is set to zero and the loop is aborted. But it is not detected, if there are other reasons for the patch failure.

The circumvention of `\process@me` is a trick to prevent doubling of `#` in the third argument of `\patchcmd`, since it is used as argument of another command (`\@whilenum`).

**Remark:**

- `\myarg/` is used for `#1`, otherwise `\patchcmd` is not happy, if a space if following `#1`.

### Improvement (by egreg)

Package `regexpatch` provides `\xpatchcmd` with a star form, which replaces all matches without the need to program a loop manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\def\ae@test#1{%
  \typeout{\detokenize{** #1 **}}%
  \textcolor{red}{\fbox{#1}}%
}
\let\myarg\relax
\edef\aetest#1{\expandonce{\ae@test{\myarg/}}}
\xpatchcmd*{\aetest}{\myarg/}{#1}{}{%
  \errmessage{Patching \noexpand\aetest failed}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \aetest{Hello}
\end{document}
```

`\myarg/` instead of `\myarg` is also needed for `\xpatchcmd`, because a space is following `#1` in `\ae@test`.

Comment: Ah! The problem of MWE.  `\let\aetest\ae@test` won't work because they're not meant to be equivalent (even though that's the way I wrote the above example).  Further, there may be other content within the definition of `\aetest` that I do want expanded.  So while your answer works for this particular case, it doesn't work for a general case.

Comment: I've updated the question to better reflect the issue.

Comment: Well you've definitely explained the why.

Comment: @A.Ellett I have added a more complex version, if the `\expandafter` trick would become to lengthy.

Comment: Awesome!  And an example of using `\patch` that makes a lot of sense to me.

Comment: Could some kind of a `lowercase` trick also be used here perhaps?

Comment: @A.Ellett `\lowercase` does not have an influence on doubling hash tokens.

Comment: With `regexpatch` you can do `\xpatchcmd*{\aetest}{\myarg}{#1}{}{}`, which will change all occurrences of `\myarg` with `#1`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\unexpanded` from eTeX using the following code:

```
\def\aeAtest#1{\textcolor{red}{\fbox{#1}}}

\def\eonce#1{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1{##1}}}
\edef\tmp{\def\noexpand\OUT##1{expanded before \eonce{\aeAtest} after.}}\tmp

\message{\meaning\OUT}
% \OUT#1 -> expanded before \textcolor {red}{\fbox {#1}} after.
```

**Edit** Another usage of the same idea defines the `\oedef` macro:

```
\def\eonce#1#2{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1{#2}}}
\def\eodef#1#2{\edef\tmp{\def\noexpand#1####1{#2}}\tmp}

\def\aeAtest#1{\textcolor{red}{\fbox{#1},#1}}
\eodef\aetest{expanded ##1+y before \eonce\aeAtest{#1+x} after.}

\message{\meaning\aetest}
% \aetest#1 -> expanded #1+y before \textcolor {red#1}{\fbox {#1+x},#1+x} after.
```

Unfortunately, the `\eodef` macro has a curious syntax: the parameter can't be presented in the parameter mask and this parameter must be typed as `##1` in "normal" positions but as `#1` in the parameter of `\eonce`.

Comment: Very nice solution.  It would probably get more attention if you kept your macro names more in line with the choices I made: your `\aeAtest`=`\ae@test`, your  `\OUT`=`\aetest`.

Comment: @A.Ellett The name `\ae@test` is somewhat impractical for me because I must to do catcode dancing when such name occurs.

Comment: I'm intrigued.  Why bothered by something that seems as prevalent as `\makeatletter`?  Again, intrigued and just curious.

Comment: @A.Ellett First of all, I must to define `\makeatletter` because plain TeX doesn't define it (and I don't use LaTeX).

Comment: Aaaah.  I get it now.  I hadn't noticed that your answers are always in TeX and not LaTeX.  Sloppy me for not noticing.  :-)

Comment: Why does `\eodef` have `####1`? Where does the number 4 come from?

Comment: @1010011010 `\eodef\foo{text}` expands to `\edef\tmp{\def\noexpand\foo##1{text}}\tmp` because the number of hash marks is multiplied by onehalf for each definition process. Then `\tmp` is defined and it expands to `\def\foo#1{text}`.

Answer (score 3):

To work around the expansion issues point to by @HeikoOberdiek, I've come up with the following work around

```
\edef\aetest#1{\noexpand\def\noexpand\ae@tmp{#1}%%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\ae@test{\ae@tmp}}}
```

though I'll have to test it out a bit before I'm sure that it really does accomplish what I want.

Comment: The macros inside `\ae@test` will see `\ae@tmp` instead of `#1`. Most macros won't care much about this. But some require, that `#1` is not hidden inside a macro, examples: `\def\ae@test#1{\selectlanguage{#1}}` with package `babel`. Then `babel` will complain about an unknown language `ae@tmp`. Another example, package `url`: `\def\ae@test#1{\url{#1}}` will print `\ae@tmp` as URL instead of the URL given in `#1`.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \ae_test:n #1
 {
  \textcolor{red}{\fbox{#1}}~
  \textcolor{green}{\fbox{#1}}~
  \textcolor{blue}{\fbox{#1}}
 }

\group_begin:
\tl_set:No \l_tmpa_tl { \ae_test:n { #1 } }
\use:x
 {
  \group_end:
  \cs_new:Npn \exp_not:N \aetest ##1
   {
    something~expandable~
    \exp_not:V \l_tmpa_tl
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\raggedright

\texttt{\meaning\aetest}

\bigskip

\aetest{Hello}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation: in `\l_tmpa_tl`, we get the replacement text of `\ae_test:n` with `##1` in place of `#1`. So we just need to expand once this token list inside another (temporary) definition. The `\use:x` trick provides this without the need of defining another temporary macro. I used `\group_begin:` and `\group_end:` not to leave `\l_tmpa_tl` modified, but it's not necessary.

Comment: How is it that you're able to set `\l_tmpa_tl` and not get an error about an illegal parameter (for the `#1`)?

Comment: @A.Ellett Because `\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {...}` is not just `\def\l_tmpa_tl{...}`, but `\cs_set_nopar:Npx \l_tmpa_tl { \exp_not:o { ... } }`, so the `#` are doubled before the token list is set. Similarly, `\tl_set:Nn` does `\cs_set_nopar:Npx #1 { \exp_not:n { #2 } }`

Comment: I guess my homework for my summer break will be to thoroughly reread the TeX Book.  I feel like I keep getting tripped up on the same few concepts.  :*(

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment I suspect, so I'll just put it here. Something that helped me a lot but I don't see it mentioned anywhere is the following. It might be really obvious, but it might also not.

Take the situation as follows. You have your two macros, one which you want to expand, the other which must hold the expanded definition:

```
\def\expandthis#1{\textcolor{red}{\fbox{#1}}}
\def\macrowithexpandeddefinition#1{\expandthis{#1}}
```

In order to get what you want, you have to work your way backwards (it will be apparent soon what I mean with this). This requires some knowledge about the idea of tokens, which I'm going to assume you're familiar with. The trickery has to happen in the line with `\def\macrowithexpandeddefinition#1`. In order to expand `\expandthis` once, we just have to reach the escape character `\` of that macro without expanding anything before that.

Step 1: jump over the last token before `\expandthis`, which is a brace `{`:

```
\def\macrowithexpandeddefinition#1\expandafter{\expandthis{#1}}
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Step 2: We must now reach the first `\expandafter`. There last token before it is `1`:

```
\def\macrowithexpandeddefinition#\expandafter1\expandafter{\expandthis{#1}}
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Step 3 and follows: The last token before that is the `#` (hash) token, continue:

```
\def\macrowithexpandeddefinition\expandafter#\expandafter1\expandafter{\expandthis{#1}}
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^
```

And repeat with the last two tokens `\macrowithexpandeddefinition` and `\def` respectively:

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\macrowithexpandeddefinition\expandafter#\expandafter1\expandafter{\expandthis{#1}}
```

You can repeat these steps for any macro you like for fine grained expansion control, but it won't make the code very readable. Also note that what I end up with is exactly the same as Heiko's "workaround".

Comment: I appreciate the *comment/answer*.  But there was never any difficulty understanding Heiko's answer.  The problem is that my MWE  was a bit misleading since this approach really doesn't work in the scenario I'm actually working on.

Comment: @A.Ellett I'm interested. Do you have a self-contained file that I can see where you're trying to get something done but this approach doesn't work?

Comment: The matter most recently came up when I was writing [an answer to another question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244161/22413).  In particular, I wanted to be able to create a user interface to change the comment formatting macro `\ae@question@row@comment@formatting` so that it could depend on the row.  For this I would have to expand it each time I use it while setting up the table.  If I waited until the moment of executing the table, then only the most recent version would come into play.  More details later.  For now I've got to run.

Comment: @A.Ellett Do I understand correctly that you want to have an extra key which controls the row colour?

Comment: No quite.  I was going to create a key in which the user could define the formatting for the comment.  I was going to set it up to require the key to take the body of a macro definition requiring at most one argument.  Then the formatting could be anything ranging from setting color, boldness of font, boxing the content, or virtually anything achievable using a macro.  Once I understood that the OP was very new to LaTeX, I chose not to confuse the issue.  At that point I started experimenting on my own with handling such macros and came across the current situation about `\unexpanded` and `#1`

Comment: @A.Ellett I'd say that a helper command would go a long way. You can define the helper command with a key and expand it inside your `\ae@question@row@comment@formatting`... If I understand you correctly