# When passing TeX code to Lua and back to TeX, the # symbol doubles

Tags: luatex

Consider the following MWE. If I pass some TeX code to Lua (via `\directlua`) and Lua tries to pass it back to TeX (via `tex.sprint`), the following problem becomes apparent.

The code below prints

```
text is  \newcommand {\foo }{##1} \foo  end
```

As you can see, the `#` doubles once passed to Lua, and of course this breaks the macro `\foo`.

It's necessary to wrap the `text` argument in `\detokenize` or similar, in order to stop TeX expanding it before passing to to Lua, but both `\detokenize` and `\unexpanded` have this issue.

This question: [Macro char `#` doubles when made letter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448972/3406) is probably the same phenomenon. And also [How do I expand exactly once a macro which takes an argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244458/3406).

Suggestions on how to work around this would be appreciated. I'd obviously prefer an approach whereby I wrap the argument passed to `luafun` inside `\NewDocumentCommand` in something, rather than adding extra special code to every occurence of `#` in my text.

And in this context, are there any other unpleasant surprises lurking in the wings with other special TeX characters? If so, please warn me now.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{fn.lua}
function luafun (text)
   texio.write_nl(string.format([[text is %s end]], text))
   tex.sprint(text)
end
\end{filecontents*}
\directlua{local scratch = require "fn.lua"}

\NewDocumentCommand{\luafun}{+m}
{
  \directlua{luafun([[\detokenize{#1}]])}
  %\directlua{luafun([[\unexpanded{#1}]])}
}
\begin{document}

\luafun
{
  \newcommand{\foo}[1]{#1}
  %\foo{foo}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The correct way to pass TeX tokens to Lua is with `\directlua{luafun("\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#1}}")}`.  Everything else will suffer from things like the hash doubling problem.

Comment: @HenriMenke I was just posting exactly the same as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `\unexpanded` here because of it's toks-like behaviour. You also need to properly escape the tokens, so `[[ .. ]]` won't work. Try instead

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\luafun}{+m}
  {%
    \directlua{luafun("\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#1}}")}%
  }
```

Comment: Additional spaces in the code also addressed ....

Comment: "toks-like behaviour"?

Comment: Thanks. I'm relieved the solution is so simple. I had horrid visions of having to pepper my text with abstruse code in order to get it to work.

Comment: Why are the extra `%` needed? I realise they get rid of newlines, but why is that a an issue here?

Comment: "toks" is presumably a reference to the macro `\toks`, which (I think) is a token register. But the relevance still escapes me.

Comment: @FaheemMitha standard tex issue try `X\luafun{xxx}X`  without the `%` you get additional space in the typeset output.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Standard TeX behaviour: end-of-line converts to space, so if you don't 'kill' them you get spaces in the output

Comment: @FaheemMitha Yes, I mean that the behaviour is that of a `toks` register: they have special rules for `#` tokens, which you need here

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and Joseph: I see. So extra space in the output of `\luafun`.